# Function to convert "camel case" type text to text with spaces in between? ie: HelloWorld --> Hello World

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Anyone know of a nice efficient function that could convert, for example:
HelloWorld -->  Hello World
helloWorld -->  Hello World
Hello_World -->  Hello World
hello_World -->  Hello World

It would be nice to be able to handle all these situations.

Preferably in in VB.Net, or C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don´t know if this is the most efficient way. But this method works fine:

**EDIT 1:** I have include Char.IsUpper suggestion in the comments

**EDIT 2:** included another suggestion in the comments: *ToCharArray is superfluous because string implements enumerable ops as a char too, i.e. foreach (char character in input)*

**EDIT 3:** I've used StringBuilder, like @Dan commented.

```
    public string CamelCaseToTextWithSpaces(string input)
    {


        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        input = input.Replace("_", "");

        foreach (char character in input)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(character))
            { 
                output.Append(' ');             
            }

            if (output.Length == 0)
            {
                // The first letter must be always UpperCase
                output.Append(Char.ToUpper(character));
            }
            else
            {
                output.Append(character);
            }                
        }

        return output.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

Comment: Nice revision, BTW, the ToCharArray is superfluous because string implements enumerable ops as a char too, i.e. `foreach (char character in input)`.
The reason I am watching this thread is the the moment it was asked I needed a "pascal case to human readable text" snippet in my code. I love stackoverflow!!  :-)

Comment: @Javier: You should probably use the `StringBuilder` class for this; every time you have `output += something` you're creating a whole new string object, whereas `StringBuilder` has the ability to append to itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other possibilities you might want to cater for - for instance, you probably don't want to add spaces to abbreviations/acronyms.

I'd recommend using:

```
Private CamelCaseConverter As Regex = New Regex("(?<char1>[0-9a-z])(?<char2>[A-Z])", RegexOptions.Compiled + RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)

Public Function CamelCaseToWords(CamelCaseString As String) As String
 Return CamelCaseConverter.Replace(CamelCaseString, "${char1} ${char2}")
End Function

'Gives:
'CamelCase => Camel Case
'PIN => PIN
```

What it doesn't do is uppercase the first letter of the first word, but you can look at the other examples for ways of doing that, or maybe someone can come up with a clever RegEx way of doing it.

Comment: ... although, having just done some reading, you may want to avoid the Compiled Regex flag unless you're doing a _lot_ of calls to the RegEx.

Comment: If you're new to .NET, the above code requires you to import System.Text.RegularExpressions. As the sample is VB.NET, you'd use:

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Answer (score 0):

Sounded fun so I coded it the most important part is the [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) take a look at this site for more documentation.

```
private static string BreakUpCamelCase(string s)
{
    MatchCollection MC = Regex.Matches(s, @"[0-9a-z][A-Z]");
    int LastMatch = 0;
    System.Text.StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Match M in MC)
    {
        SB.AppendFormat("{0} ", s.Substring(LastMatch, M.Index + 1 - LastMatch));
        LastMatch = M.Index + 1;
    }
    if (LastMatch < s.Length)
    {
        SB.AppendFormat("{0} ", s.Substring(LastMatch));
    }
    return SB.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I see that you are hoarding your punctuation.  Once everyone else has used up all the punctuation they have, you will be rich!  Clever...